# Confirmation pop-up with coffescript buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am having in my view 4 buttons implemented in coffescript , here is the view

```
 %button#warn.button{:type => "submit"}
      Warn
    %button#ban.button{:type => "submit"}
      Ban
    %button#delete.button{:type => "submit"} , 
      Delete
    %button#hide.button{:type => "submit"}
      Hide
```

In the js.coffee file , this is what I wrote

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#warn").click ->
    target = "check_warned"
    $("#needs_form").attr "action", target
    $("#needs_form").submit()

  $("#ban").click ->
    target = "ban "
    $("#needs_form").attr "action", target
    $("#needs_form").submit()

  $("#delete").click ->
    target = " delete "
    $("#needs_form").attr "action", target
    $("#needs_form").submit()

  $("#hide").click ->
    target = " hide "
    $("#needs_form").attr "action", target
    $("#needs_form").submit()
```

Now I need to add a confirmation pop up with "Are you sure you want to delete these posts?" when I click on the delete button.. Any help about how to embed it in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your delete click function:

```
$("#delete").click ->
  if window.confirm("are you sure?)
    target = " delete "
    $("#needs_form").attr "action", target
    $("#needs_form").submit()
```

Comment: Sorry I have anothe rquestion concerning the same part , if I want to use ajax after pressing delete button , how can this be doable? What I understand is that I have to user form_remote_tag instead od form_tag but there is an error:undefined method `form_remote_tag' for #<#<Class:0x007fe34d41d330>:0x007fe34d3d4ba8>